# Accessing C pointers to vertices in Blender's Python API

Tags: python, scripting, linux, external-applications, source-code

I'm currently making a render engine in C and C++ for Blender. I want to access the vertices of a mesh from C via a pointer, to reduce the time spent in Python and avoid unneeded data duplication.

I am aware that objects derived from the `ID` class, there is an `as_pointer()` method available. However, when I tried to use `as_pointer()` on the vertices collection of a mesh like so:

```py
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
pointer = mesh.vertices.as_pointer()
```

I received an error stating that `bpy_prop_collection` object has no attribute `as_pointer`, which makes sense as `bpy_prop_collection` isn't derived from `ID`.

The documentation mentions states that the type of `vertices`is "MeshVertices bpy_prop_collection of MeshVertex, (readonly)" ([doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.vertices)), and `MeshVertices` should be abe to return a pointer, but this isn't the type of neither `vertices` nor it elements.

As a workaround, I've been retrieving the vertices data into a numpy array which is then passed onto my C library, as shown in the following example code:

```py
import bpy
import numpy as np
import ctypes

obj = bpy.context.object  # Suppose 'obj' is the mesh object
mesh = obj.data

# Allocate an array and copy the data, then set the pointer
# of the struct to the array
vert_array = np.zeros((len(mesh.vertices) * 3), dtype=np.float32)
mesh.vertices.foreach_get("co", vert_array)
vert_ptr = vert_array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))

# Pass the pointer
lib = ctypes.CDLL("bin/libengine.so")
lib.load_vert.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.float)]
lib.load_vert(vert_ptr)
```

However, this approach duplicates the vertex data in memory (once in Blender's internal data structures, and once in the numpy array) and require processing which could be avoided.

I've looked into Blender's source code and noticed that the underlying C/C++ API does allow direct memory access. By looking at the `BKE_mesh_vert_positions` and `CustomData_get_layer_named` functions, we see that the vertices are stored in a contiguous data block:

```c
BLI_INLINE const float (*BKE_mesh_vert_positions(const Mesh *mesh))[3]
{
  return (const float(*)[3])CustomData_get_layer_named(&mesh->vdata, CD_PROP_FLOAT3, "position");
}
```

```c
const void *CustomData_get_layer_named(const CustomData *data,
                                       const eCustomDataType type,
                                       const char *name)
{
  int layer_index = CustomData_get_named_layer_index(data, type, name);
  if (layer_index == -1) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  return data->layers[layer_index].data;
}
```

This means that we could have, at least in theory, a pointer to the data.

Is there a method in the Python API to expose these pointers or a way to work with the C/C++ API from Python to get this memory directly, without having to compile a custom version of Blender?

Any guidance on how to directly access these pointers or alternative solutions that avoid memory duplication would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module can create a C-compatible array from a Python list of Vertex objects. But you can also just take the pointer of the first vertex `mesh.vertices[0].as_pointer()` because the pointer to the first element is also the pointer to the entire array. I tested this on Windows 11 but it should also work on Linux. I compiled the following C code `print_pointer.c` using the Ubuntu app with cross-compiler command `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared -o print_pointer.dll print_pointer.c`. I assume you are on Linux and  compiled it with `gcc -shared -fPIC -o print_pointer.so print_pointer.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float* data;
    int num_vertices;
} VertexData;

void print_pointer(VertexData* vertex_data) {
    printf("Vertices:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex_data->num_vertices; i += 3) {
        float* vertex = vertex_data->data + i;
        printf("Vertex %d: (%f, %f, %f)\n", i / 3, vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]);
    }
}
```

Here's the Python script:

```
import bpy
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('/path/to/dll_or_so/print_pointer.dll') # in your case your .so 

class VertexData(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)), ("num_vertices", ctypes.c_int)]

obj = bpy.context.object
mesh = obj.data

num_vertices = len(mesh.vertices) * 3
ptr = mesh.vertices[0].as_pointer()
ptr_as_float = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
vertex_data = VertexData(ptr_as_float, num_vertices)

lib.print_pointer(ctypes.byref(vertex_data))
```

Result for the Default Cube:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Now that I think about it, I knew the array was contiguous in C, and I knew it was possible to get a vertex pointer, so it should have been obvious to me, but apparently not. Thanks again

Comment: you're welcome! i'm glad it worked out for you, good luck on that render engine! :)